# min-width in Bootstrap for different screen sizes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table in my Bootstrap layout - it will mainly be viewed on desktops so I want to give the table a min width of 1000px.

But I'm mindful that it's possible the page could be viewed on a tablet or mobile as well. So on those devices I just want the table to take up what the browser considers an appropriate amount (ie. not have any min-width).

Is this possible? I was looking at the media queries part of http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries but that didn't make a lot of sense to me.

```
    .table-custom {
    min-width: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    ...
```

Thanks

Comment: Just remove the min-width property, that causes your table to be always atleast 1000px.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use twitter bootstrap then it will be easy for u as an example

```
<table class="table-custom col-lg-8 col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-3"></table>
```

It will adjust its size according to device

Comment: OP wants table with min width 1000 in desktop

Comment: then also min-width can be set after bootstrap col class

Comment: Also he puts width 100% , how does col-lg-8 gives 100% width?

Comment: I am just giving an example..divide page like http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries and then set bootstrap class

Comment: Give a complete working example, with css to set min width, and col-12 for 100% width

Comment: see this example how table width is automatically adjust by that col classes http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_table_basic&stacked=h

Comment: you can see this one also in which col class is used http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/examples.html.. its easy with bootstrap class